# Error flutter box decoration image no working with unexpected error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm getting the this error

[image]

error on a BoxDecoration saying "Cannot provide both a color and a decoration"

What should I do to resolve the issue? here is the file where it occurs:

```dart
...
child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.blue,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0XFFEF6C00),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50)
              )  
          ),
          child: ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the error you are getting you cannot use both color and decoration properties in a Container.
The correct way to provide a color when you also want to give different types of BoxDecoration is by adding the color options inside the BoxDecoration

### DO

```dart
...
child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(...)
 ),
),
```

### DON'T

```dart
...
child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.blue,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(...)
 ),
),
```

The second method of adding color to a container will return the error you are getting.

Comment: ``` Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 230,
                width: 160,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                ),``` but still got the same error

Comment: @DEV0G Could it be you used the color parameter both inside and outside a BoxDecoration in multiple parts of your code?

Comment: what do i do because it not still owrking

Comment: @DEV0G Can you please share the code where you are getting your error and a screenshot of your error as an image uploaded on imgur? Thanks